# Publishing measurements

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a set of performance tests, which measure the amount of lines a printer is capable of printing per minute. Currently we're using the `Measurement Plots` plugin, but we'd like to see the whole history of these measurements on the main page of each job, pretty much the same way as `Test Result Trend` (as opposed to going into each test case every time we run a cycle, and looking at every plot, even if there is no decline/improvement).

Is there some alternative, preferably as easy-to-use as `Measurement Plots` (i.e. throw an XML string into the standard output, and it just works, out of the box)? I've checked out `Performance Plugin`, but it seems to be an overkill for such a simple task, and I'm not even sure how we'd generate JMeter files anyway (like, yes, we can generate them with a Python script or something of that sort, but there's no documentation on the matter, other than the .xsl files found in the sources of JMeter, so the whole development process will be a big trial'n'error nightmare).